# Adding participants to a conversation

Tags: botframework

How can you add a participants to a conversation between a user and a bot, for example to escalate a discussion to a person from the helpdesk?

I've tried to add a participant to the Participants collection in the reply message, but nothing happens. I've tested this using the Skype channel.

Answer (score 2):

I think that scenario it's not yet supported. I reported something similar time ago in GitHub. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/145)